# How do I Build a LEGO Digestive System?

Tags: instructions, design

How might I build a LEGO model of a digestive system? I think it could be a good way of helping my son with a science project.

Either building plans, instructions, or any help with getting started would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this may be a question which we will have a hard time to answer. However, you may be interested to know that Nathan Sawaya, LEGO Certified Professional, once made a [heart model for an hospital](http://brickartist.com/gallery/heart/?tag=large). I suppose contacting an LCP for this might be overkill, but it might inspire your kid - although it probably doesn't need to be so accurate for a school project.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it very simple with just building the organs with regular bricks. Color code each organ. I have never seen anyone do this with LEGO bricks so can't link to a picture, however I can imagine than it could be done easily. Basically you would end up with a pipe-system. ;)